# Gem not found when I have just installed it

Tags: ruby, excel, cpanel

I am creating a Ruby script which reads data from an Excel sheet and put its data on a MySQL database. I have written it and installed the necessary gems. However, when I try to run it via my cPanel host and I get the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- ruby-mysql (LoadError) [1] => from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require' [2] => from ../ruby/InsertarFaltantesExcel.rb:2 )
```

Ruby Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-mysql'
require 'spreadsheet'
#load './spreadsheet.rb'

con = Mysql.connect('xx', 'xx', 'xx','xx')

ARGV = "--help" if ARGV.empty?

workbook = Spreadsheet.open(ARGV[0])
sheet = workbook.worksheet(0)

sheet.each do |row|
  @faltantes = {
  "id_verificador" => "#{row[0]}",
  "order_id" => "#{row[1]}",
  "id_proveedor" => "#{row[28]}",
  "shipping" => "#{row[10]}",
  "ean" => "#{row[4]}",
  "isbn" => "#{row[5]}",
  "description" => "#{row[8]}",
  "sku" => "#{row[9]}",
  "cost" => "#{row[40]}",
  "order_price" => "#{row[14]}",
  "master" => "#{row[39]}",
  "quantity_purchased" => "#{row[11]}",
  "total_price" => "#{row[12]}",
  "condition" => "#{row[33]}",
  "tracking" => "#{row[29]}"      
  }

  insertar_faltantes(@faltantes, con)
end

def insertar_faltantes(hash, con)
    statement - con.prepare("INSERT INTO articulos(art_id_verificador, art_id_orden, art_id_proveedor, art_shipping, art_N13, art_ISBN, art_titulo, art_SKU, art_cost, art_precio, art_master, art_cantidad, art_total, art_condition,
     art_tracking) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);")
   statement.execute "#{hash['id_verificador']}", "#{hash['order_id']}", "#{hash['id_proveedor']}", "#{hash['shipping']}", "#{hash['ean']}", "#{hash['isbn']}", "#{hash['sku']}", "#{hash['cost']}", "#{hash['order_price']}","#{hash['master']}",
 "#{hash['quantity_purchased']}", "#{hash['condition']}", "#{hash['tracking']}"
end
```

Comment: Do you know where your gems are located? Try looking there to see whether it is installed. It's probably somewhere around `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/`

Comment: Actually, it's not in that specific location you mentioned. Rather it's on here:

`~/ruby/gems/gems/`

Comment: Are the other gems in the same place? I presume they all work.

Comment: @SekalfNroc: yes, they are in the same place. And, oddly enough, only `rubygems` works. The others don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gems in `~/ruby/gems/gems/` are not being recognised by your Ruby executable. Find where all the other gems are being kept and move these ones into there.

Alternatively, try using a different package manager. If you have installed gems successfully in the past, use the manager you used for that.

Comment: Hello, I have used Ruby in the past to install its gems. I don't know if that is what you mean.

Comment: `gem install <gem>`

Comment: The problematic gems are in the same place as the ones that work? Try deleting and reinstalling them.

Comment: I am looking and it seems the answer is no. The non-problematic one is on two places: one on `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/` and the other on `~/ruby/gems/gems/`, where the problematic ones are.

Comment: If you install them all in the same way, they should be in the same place. Try calling `gem install` again on the ones that don't work.